# How can I send elements in csv file to variables in Python?

Tags: python, excel, csv

I have an excel/csv file containing information in the following format:

```
    A     B     C  
1   3     A     T
2   5     T     G
3  100    A     C
4  101    A     A
```

I would like to set var1 to 3, var2 to A, and var3 to T, run some operations with these variables, and do the same on the next row. I.e. next pass would set var1 to 5, var2 to T, var3 to G, run the operations, and so on.

What is the best way to accomplish this in Python? I'm fairly new to programming in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the CSV and then take advantage of the fact that everything is separated by commas.  Note how we use `[1:]` to ignore the first line.

```
f = open("yourcsv.csv","r")
lines = f.readlines()
for i in lines[1:]:
    split_line = i.split()
    var1 = split_line[1]
    var2 = split_line[2]
    var3 = split_line[3]
    # Do something with the values
```

**EDIT:**

In the comments, you said that ABC/1234 are the excel markings.  If so, the following will work.

```
f = open("yourcsv.csv","r")
lines = f.readlines()
for i in lines:
    split_line = i.split()
    var1 = split_line[0]
    var2 = split_line[1]
    var3 = split_line[2]
    # Do something with the values
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I was using ABC/1234 to indicate the row/column in Excel. Is [1:] still necessary?

Comment: @maharaja9933 if my answer solved your problem, could you accept it by pressing the check mark next to the answer?

Comment: @maharaja9933 Thank you!

Comment: @maharaja9933 No, `1:` is not necessary.  Let me update my answer real quick.

Answer (score 0):

you can use dict to achieve the request

```
import csv
varLst = [var1,var2,var3]
with open(filepath,'r') as f:
  r = csv.reader(f)
  for line in r:
     varDict = { v: varLst[i] for i,v in enumerate(line) }
     # do something
     # if you want call var1 ==> varDict['3'] for first line of data
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to work out an inelegant solution myself while I was waiting for responses and I figured I'd offer my own approach of the problem in case it can help someone in the future or to get feedback on it. Both methods suggested above worked as well!

```
import csv
with open('scz.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
   filereader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
   for row in filereader:
       str_row = ''.join(row)
       var1, var2, var3 = str_row.split(',')
```